# Latex: problems with equation numbers and space after the equal-sign

Tags: equations, align

I have a set of really easy formulas/equations and need to present them in the right way. And, as always, I have some trouble with the different possibilities from Latex.

My first attempt was:

```
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
 \label{eq_convert}
 p(x) &=& C \cdot x ^ {- \alpha} \nonumber \\
 ln(p(x)) &=& ln(C \cdot x ^ {- \alpha}) \nonumber \\ 
 &=& ln(C)+ln(x ^ {- \alpha}) \nonumber \\
 ln(p(x)) &=& ln(C) + ln(x) \cdot {- \alpha}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

It has only one number for the equation on the bottom, but the equations have to much space to the equal-sign and they are right-aligned after the equal-sign.
The output as an image:
[image: 1]]

Thus, I googled my problem and found a new solution with the \equation function and I know, that this is not the best way:

```
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
 p(x) &=& C \cdot x ^ {- \alpha} \\
 ln(p(x)) &=& ln(C \cdot x ^ {- \alpha})  \\ 
 &=& ln(C)+ln(x ^ {- \alpha}) \\
 ln(p(x)) &=& ln(C) + ln(x) \cdot {- \alpha}
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The result looks much better, but I want the counting-number on the bottom.
[[image: 2]]

I asked this question first in Stack Overflow, but don't get an answer (probably I'm too impatient), anyway, I think this is the right place to ask it.
Any ideas how to solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE. First suggestion: isn't `$ln$` but `$\ln$`.

Comment: Just replace `&=&` (the old `eqnarray` syntax) by `&=`. And to ahve the numbering at the bottom use `\begin{aligned}[b]` instead of `split`.

Comment: the syntax is `&=` not `&=&`

Comment: Add \usepackage[fleqn,tbtags]{amsmath} into your preamble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to fixing the syntax error by changing the four instances of `&=&` to `&=`, you may also wish to (a) switch from an `align` environment to a nested pair of `equation` and `aligned` environments -- to get rid of the need for all those `\nonumber` directives -- and (b) write `\ln` rather than just `ln` and also use fewer parentheses to declutter the "look" of the equations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % choose a suitable document class
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq_convert}
\begin{aligned}[b] % "[b]" for bottom alignment of eqn. number
     p(x) &= C x ^ {- \alpha} \\
 \ln p(x) &= \ln(C x ^ {- \alpha}) \\
          &= \ln C +\ln(x ^ {- \alpha})  \\
          &= \ln C - \alpha\ln x 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```